# Weird Spacing with Paid Google Site Search

Tags: html, css

I am hoping that someone here can be helpful. I am currently using the paid Google site search on my work website with default settings:

http://thermosealinsulation.ca/search_results.htm

If you do any type of search, say for insulation, you will notice a strange spacing of about 8 lines before the search results begin.

Why is this happening and how can I correct it?

Comment: When I take the GCS content outside of your site's context, there is no blank space. See http://jsfiddle.net/ETTdd/ (I took the HTML from the GCS results, and put that directly into your site's body). This means that there is something in your site's design / layout is affecting the GCS content.

Comment: @KatieK - if Till's solution doesn't work, do you have any idea where I would even begin trying to find the root of the problem?

Comment: For something like this, I generally copy a page, and then remove large blocks of code until the problems goes away.  By iterating in this manner, I can identify the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the implications but setting the following css properties should remove the empty space:

```
.gsc-resultsHeader { clear: none; }
.gsc-webResult:after { clear: none; }
```

Make sure this is happening after those g**gle css files are loaded - and again: not sure what this might do to the functionality.

Comment: worked like a charm! I copied the default css and loaded it in my site with your changes - and voila, that unwanted space is gone. Thank you so much for your help. Hope you have a great day!